# How to upload images when clicking on a div, not submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

I had code before that allows: when user click the submit div, the text inside the contenteditable div will be passing to upload.php using Jquery, insert into database then immediately returned. Now I'm trying to add function that also could process images. ie. upload to upload.php, insert in mysql database, then show up immediately after storage. How can I modify the code below to achieve this? When I did the research the posting images are handled by form submitting button which I don't want.

HTML and CSS

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="topic_content_input" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <input multiple class="fileInput" type="file" id="files" name="files[]"/>
  <br>
  <div id="submit" > click me to pass the photo to upload.php</div>
  <div name="topicreturn"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){

            var txtContent = $("#topic_content_input").text();
                if(txtContent){

                    $.post("upload.php", {txtContent:txtContent}, function(result){
                        $("div[name=topicreturn]").prepend(result);
                        $("#topic_content_input").text('');
                    });
                 }
})
})

</script>

<style>
#topic_content_input{
    height: 60px;
    width:350px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#submit{
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

PHP file (upload.php)

```
<?php
require('connect.php');


$content=$_POST["txtContent"];

$sql="insert into topics (content) VALUES ('".$content."')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
            echo $content;
        }
        else{
            echo $content;

        }

?>
```

Comment: use ajax with form-data ....

Comment: Try this https://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

**Form submit() Method**

The submit() method submits the form (same as clicking the Submit button).

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

So, your code could be

```
<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
<div id="topic_content_input" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <input multiple class="fileInput" type="file" id="files" name="files[]"/>
  <br>
  <div id="submit" onClick="subForm();"> click me to pass the photo to upload.php</div>
  <div name="topicreturn"></div>
</form>

<script>
function subForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you help giving some details on php file so I can test it?

Comment: Why to submit a for though ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the div id to listen the click in jquery

```
  $(".business-bottom-content").click(
    function()
    {
       var txtContent = $("#topic_content_input").text();
            if(txtContent){

                $.post("upload.php", {txtContent:txtContent}, function(result){
                    $("div[name=topicreturn]").prepend(result);
                    $("#topic_content_input").text('');
                });
             }
   });
```